# What is required for attribution?

Tags: discussion, plagiarism, attribution

I recently had an answer deleted due to it being "copied without attribution", but I linked back to the original author's profile and to the original question and answer that I pulled code from. I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/) and my answer seems to have hit all those points. Does that post cover everything that needs to be done to show attribution or are there other rules that must be followed?

Comment: If you are attempting to answer a question by using an existing Q&A on Stack Overflow then you should be flagging the question as a duplicate instead.

Comment: In addition to the linked blog post, there is [this article in the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing). It's a fairly recent addition, so I never think to link to it, but it is there and it does provide a very clear example.

Comment: @BSMP That's 90% true. The exception is when you have to *adapt* the code to work in a slightly different situation. Then, the questions are not duplicates, but you still want to use someone else's code, so you need to provide attribution.

Comment: @CodyGray I'd say if you have to adapt the code to work in a *significantly* different situation that'd be right. Just because code cannot be simply copied and pasted to work does not mean the question isn't a duplicate. You need more than a *slightly* different situation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

BSMP got it right in that you should be flagging the question as a duplicate if an answer from a previous question applies with minimal or no modifications.

That said, the moderator's claim that the code was copied without attribution does seem to be mistaken. You did attribute the code to the original author with a link to their answer and you did state that you made some modifications to it to suit the question you were answering. Here's the relevant portion of your answer:

> The code was taken from [Samuel Meddows'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/525895/samuel-meddows) accepted answer to the question [How do I get the current date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-do-i-get-the-current-date-in-javascript?rq=1) and then tweaked to work with the `min` attribute of the HTML `input` tag.

That counts as attribution to me.

The moderator who deleted your answer had also deleted *two* other answers, both of which *did* copy from the same accepted answer *without* attribution. It's entirely possible they missed the attribution in yours and left the same comment based on the appearance of the code snippet, or they left it on the wrong answer since the comment appears to be missing from one of the other answers.

Comment: Definitely counts as attribution. This is perfect, and exactly [what we ask for](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/). The only concern is that [it was missing in the initial revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45529119/1).

Comment: Yeah but there was over an hour between the current revision and deletion - I seriously doubt the moderator left the question hanging for that long before going to town with the answers. I'm not at all concerned about the initial revision given that the user was able to correct their own omission in the meantime with no prompting from anyone whatsoever - which gets *serious* kudos from me.

Comment: Mea Culpa, I had indeed missed the attribution. I saw a page full of multiple copies of the same answer, all apparently copied where they should just have closed the question as a duplicate.