# Answer to question on SO on unix.stackexchange

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, cross-posting, site-crossover

If there is a question on SO with an answer that solves the problem on unix.stackexchange, is it right (is it possible?) to close the question on SO as duplicate of the one on unix?

Comment: Nope, not possible.

Comment: Nope.  You can't cross site dupe.  Best you can do is comment, and possibly vote to close it as off topic if it is not on topic for SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, SE does not support cross-site duplicates.

You can

- link to answer in comment
- ask for migration (most likely custom flag to moderator) and if/when complete mark original question as duplicate of migrated one.
- create answer with link and quote/summary of the answer (See [What is required for attribution?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354666/what-is-required-for-attribution) and similar on guidance how to provide proper attribution). Mark it Community Wiki unless you add your own content. (This is likely the best and most reliable route)

Note that some questions may be on-topic on both sites, if not - make sure to vote to close appropriately. If question on SO closed you still need to keep attribution to it (even if it may be deleted).